# Changing the getROW index in apachee POI throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am trying to write to Excel using apachee POI. It works when the getrow index is 0 like[getrow(o)]. But changing it other than zero throw nullpointer exception.

```
package fairfoxchecking;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class writingInExcel {
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {

    File src = new File("D:/Etl_Bug_reporting_Template.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet1 =wb.getSheetAt(0);

    sheet1.getRow(0).createCell(5).setCellValue("cheasdfasdfasck1");
    sheet1.getRow(1).createCell(5).setCellValue("cheasdfasdfasck1");

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);
    wb.write(fout);
    wb.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you do create a cell, you have to ensure the row is created.

Try something like,

```
if(sheet1.getRow(rowIndex) == null)
      sheeet1.createRow(rowIndex)
sheet1.getRow(rowIndex).createCell(colIndex).setCellValue(stringVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow(int)) , getRow might return null if it is not defined. So you might have to create one before writing.

`sheet1.createRow(index)`

---

Check this [lib](http://codoid.com/fillo/) - seems to be nice.

Comment: Please ensure to call createRow() only if there is currently none at that index as otherwise you will overwrite existing rows with newly created ones.